# Resizing Image inside carousel

Tags: html, css

I created a carousel with images inside. But one of the images appear to be very big while the other is blur but fits well. I tried resizing with CSS but it's not working. What should I do?

Here is what I mean
This First screenshot shows the image fits well[shows image fits well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM1XH.png)

while in this screenshot, the image is big and it is cut off from the carousel
[shows image is cut off from carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VVvT.png)

Here is what I tried

```css
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper{
            font-family: Nunito;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            height: 100%;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        #carouselExampleIndicators{
            max-width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 0%;
        }
        .carousel-item {
             padding: 10px;
             max-width: 100%; /* Maximum width */
             margin: 0 auto;
        }
          .carousel-inner {
              width: auto;
              height: 370px;
              max-height: 370px !important;
              position: relative;
          }
         .carousel img {
             position: relative;
             top: 0;
             min-width: 100%;
             height: auto;
             max-width: 100%;
         }
    </style>
```

```html
 <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="background-color: #eeeeee;">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row" style="width: 100%;margin: 0 auto;">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="desc1">
                                    <h4 style="color: #081139;">LET'S GO!</h4>
                                    <p style="color: #081139;">Everyone needs to be on their toes in order to fight and stamp out bad eggs in the world</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="img1" style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px;">
                                    <img id="img1" src="Image/Carousel/singlestc.png" alt="First slide" height="30" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row" style="width: 100%;margin: 0 auto;">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="desc2">
                                    <h4 style="color: #081139;">WE CARE</h4>
                                    <p style="color: #081139;">We are the world, lets make it a better place for the younger generations</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="img2">
                                   <img id="img2" src="Image/Carousel/SNC.png" height="30" alt="Second slide"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the width of 2 images to be 100% of the parent, and the reason it is being cut off is `.wrapper` class has a style of `overflow: hidden`, so your images are sizing properly but the overflow is hidden.

See example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sYNQ.jpg

If you want to retain this fixed height, add styling for the `.img1` and `.img2` classes (Or create 1 img wrapper class which I world recommend more) and define the height on those, that way you can give the img elements a height of 100%, and set the width to be the variable (auto).

```
.img1, .img2 {
    height: 370px;
    max-height: 370px !important;
}
/* Or do this and add the class in place of img1 and img2 */
.img-wrapper {
    height: 370px;
    max-height: 370px !important;    
}
.carousel img {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I would however recommend editing your images to be a uniform size. That way there is no major disparities in the design.